# How to create a User's notification in web application

Tags: asp.net-core, notifications

I am currently creating a web application in asp.net core and I was wondering if anyone can give me an idea of how to build the notification for users. For example if someone replies to your post, how will you get a notification telling you? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try searching? Did you read about SignalR?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find anywhere an example was written.